# Composition of Limits In The Most General Case

Tags: calculus

We know by the composition of limits that if $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x \to b}f(x)=L$ and $g(x) \neq b$ in some neighborhood of $c$ then $$\lim_{x \to c}f(g(x))=L$$
But If we choose a function $f(x)$ which is defined on a set $X$ in such a way that every neighbourhood of $b$ contains some elements of the set $X$ and $\lim_{x \to b}f(x)=L$ and suppose we choose a function $g(x)$ such that $g:R \to Y$ and $X∩Y = \phi $ and also $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=b$ then we see that $f(g(x))$ is not defined at any point and so the limit $$\lim_{x \to c}f(g(x))$$. So how to deal with composition of limits in such cases??

Answer (score 1):

Well, $f  \circ g$ is only defined on $X \cap Y$ and that is empty, but the definition of limit requires for $h(x)=f(g(x))$ to be defined in a neighbourhood of $c$, so there is no limit...

Comment: Then how to deal with composition of limits in the general case

Comment: What do you mean by how to deal?

Comment: I mean is there no general theorem for the composition of limits in such cases???

Comment: How about [LIMITS OF COMPOSITE FUNCTIONS Milosav M. Marjanovic and Zoran Kadelburg 1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265427403_LIMITS_OF_COMPOSITE_FUNCTIONS)?